# How to remove blank space in LinearLayout inside GridView?

Tags: android, xml, gridview, android-linearlayout

I have a GridView that consists of two columns. The GridView contains LinearLayout as each item. However, there is a blank space between items.
My xml code for the GridView is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".DisplayAndCompare"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pgk_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="PACKAGES"
        android:textColor="#3b4350"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/pckg_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/pgk_search"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_season"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="compare"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/pckg_details"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My xml code for LinearLayout is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the screenshot of the application.
[image: There is a blank space below the item of the grid]
I want to remove the blank space below each item (LinearLayout) inside the GridView. How to do this?

Comment: Could you share the xml with the compare button also?

Comment: I have added the full xml of the GridView in the first part. The second part is the xml for the item inside GridView, each item is represented by a LinearLayout.

Comment: You can try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="400dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the height of the `GridView` from 400dp into `wrap_content`, so that it can't expand beyond the needed height

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/pckg_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pgk_search"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```